# If $f(nx)=f(x)^n$ then $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, monotone-functions

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ is injective monotone function and if, $f(nx)=f(x)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then,
$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y),\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$

It is easy to check the equality if $y$ is a multiple of $x$.

I thought about proving the inequalities, $f(x+y)\le f(x)f(y)$ and $f(x+y)\ge f(x)f(y)$, but I couldn't get to them.

Assuming that $f$ is increasing and $x<y$, then $y=kx+r$, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0< r\le \lvert x \rvert$, so

$$f(x+y)=f(x+kx+r)=f(x(k+1)+r)\ge f(x(k+1))=f(x)^{k+1}=f(x)f(x)^k=f(x)f(kx)$$

That is, $f(x+y)\ge f(x)f(kx)$, but the problem is that $f(kx)<f(y)$ so I can't continue the demonstration.

Comment: The proof doesn’t work for different signs of $x$ and $y$

Comment: @Fakemistake I think I can solve this if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
But the problem that I reach in the end, still persists.

Comment: We can begin by proving that the first relationship is true for rational numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the ideas presented by Mohamed Cheddadi and Martin van IJcken, it is possible to ask the question again in the following way,

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ be a monotone injective function. The statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f(nx)=f(x)^n$, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
> 2. $f(x)=a^x$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $a=f(1)$
> 3. $f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

The implication of the original question is $1. \Rightarrow 3.$, but for that we must proof $1. \Rightarrow 2.$ and then $2. \Rightarrow 3.$

$\boxed{1. \Rightarrow 2.}$ 
Assuming that $1.$ is valid, note that if $r =\frac{m}{n}, m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $f(rx)=f(x)^r$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, with $nr=m$,
$$f(rx)^n=f(nrx)=f(mx)=f(x)^m$$
So
$$f(rx)^n=f(x)^m\Rightarrow (f(rx)^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=(f(x)^m)^{\frac{1}{n}}\Rightarrow f(rx)=f(x)^{\frac{m}{n}}$$

So, if $a=f(1)$, we have to

$$f(r)=f(r\cdot 1)=f(1)^r=a^r \text{ for all } r\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Assuming without loss of generality that $f$ is an increasing function, therefore

$$1=f(x)^0 = f(0\cdot x)=f(0)<f(1)=a\Longrightarrow 1<a$$

Let's suppose by absurdity that there is $x_0 \in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x_0)\neq a^{x_0}$. Say $f(x_0)<a^{x_0}$. Then we can choose an $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$f(x_0)<a^r<a^{x_0}\Rightarrow f(x_0)<f(r)<a^{x_0}$$

As $f$ is increasing, $x_0<r$, but on the other hand, like $a>1$, then if $a^r < a^{x_0}$ we have $r<x_0$, absurd!.

$\boxed{2. \Rightarrow 3.}$ 
Assuming that $2.$ is valid,
$$f(x+y)=f(1\cdot (x+y))=f(1)^{x+y}=f(1)^x \cdot f(1)^y = f(x)\cdot f(y)$$

$\boxed{3. \Rightarrow 1.}$ 
Is trivial

Answer (score 3):

If $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ then
$$
f(x+y) = f((x+y)1) = f(1)^{x+y} = f(1)^x f(1)^y = f(x1) f(y1) = f(x)f(y).
$$

If $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ then there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $nx,ny\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Then
$$
f(x+y)^n = f(n(x+y)) = f(nx+ny) = f(nx) f(ny) = f(x)^n f(y)^n = (f(x)f(y))^n,
$$
so $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y).$

If $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ then take sequences $x_k^+, x_k^-, y_k^+, y_k^- \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_k^+\to x+,\ x_k^-\to x-,\ y_k^+\to y+,\ y_k^-\to y-$. The result then follows from density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and from monotonicity. Try to complete this step yourself.

Comment: At least for me, that final step is the most difficult part in the whole proof. Would you be able to provide more details to enlighten me?

Comment: @QC_QAOA: the last step can be done by keeping one of the variables say $y$ fixed and rational and replace $x$ with a sequence $x_n$ of rationals tending to $x$. The limit operation proves the relation for real $x$ and rational $y$. Now deal with sequence $y_n$ of rationals tending to $y$.

Comment: I think all we need is that $f$ is positive. Monotone nature is probably not needed. I consider your approach simpler than other approaches presented +1

Comment: @QC_QAOA: on a second thought I think the key part needed here is continuity of $f$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. But continuity is not given. Monotonicity is given.

Comment: Continuity at $0$ can be obtained by noting that $f(1/n)\to f(0)=1$ and then taking any sequence $x_n\to 0^+$ and showing $f(x_n) \to 1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. You're right. Continuity is easy to show. But can we use it to draw conclusions of the value of $f$ on irrationals? If we wanted to define $f$ on irrationals, this would have been a natural way to go, though.

Answer (score 3):

If $i$ is an irrational number is a limit of a sequence $r_n$ of rational numbers
$$ i= \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} r_n .$$
Thus
$$\forall N \in \mathbb N \quad \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N  \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N \quad  n \ge n_0  \Rightarrow  |i-r_n| \le \frac{1}{N}
 \Rightarrow  \quad |ix-r_nx| \le \frac{|x|}{N} \quad -\frac{|x|}{N} + r_n\cdot x \le ix \le \frac{|x|}{N} + r_n \cdot x.$$
If $x \ge 0$ then
$$f(x)^{r_n-\frac{1}{N}} \le f(ix) \le f(x)^{r_n + \frac{1}{N}}.$$
This implies that
$$f(i\cdot x) = f(x)^{i}.$$
The case $x \le 0$ is similar.

Comment: Just to put things together. The fact that $f(ix) = f(x)^i$ for $i$ irrational means that in fact $f(x) = f(1)^x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (since the same result follows for rationals). Using that fact, the result follows from $f(x + y) = f(1)^{x+y} = f(1)^x f(1)^y = f(x)f(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(\frac{p}{q}\cdot x) =f(p\cdot\frac{x}{q})=f(\frac{x}{q})^p.$$
But
$$f(x)=f(q\cdot\frac{x}{q})=f(\frac{x}{q})^q.$$
Hence
$$f(x)^{\frac{1}{q}}= f(\frac{x}{q}).$$
Thus
$$f(\frac{p}{q}\cdot x)= f(x)^{\frac{p}{q}}.$$

Comment: We can suppose that $y$ is a limit of a rational sequence $\frac{p_n}{q_n}.$

Comment: I agree with what you have said but I think that showing that $y$ is the limit of a rational sequence will take some justification (I do believe the claim however)

Comment: Every real number is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers

Comment: Yes, but $f(x)$ is not a necessarily a continuous function (this is the part that I am struggling with at least)

Comment: Would you be able to add your reasoning to your answer then? It is not obvious to me at this time that that must be the case

Comment: Monotonicity and injectivity don't grant continuity by themselves. Think in a function $f(x) = x$ for $x \in (-\infty,0]$ and $f(x) = x+1$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$. It's monotonic (strictly) and injective but not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to approach this a little bit differently - and possibly inferiorly as I will be looking only at the rational numbers so it could still be the case that the property does not hold for $x=\pi$ or some other irrational number - I will first proof that the only class of functions that satisfies the property
$$  f(nx) = f(x)^n \, \forall \,x \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{N} $$
is the class
$$f(x) = f(1)^x \,\forall \,x \in \mathbb{Q}$$

I will do this by first observing that
$$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \sqrt[n]{f(1)} \, \forall \, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

and combine that property with the original property to show that
$$ x = \frac{p}{q} \implies f(x) = \sqrt[q]{f(1)}^{p} = f(1)^x \, \forall \, p \in \mathbb{Z}, q \in \mathbb{N}$$
which would be equivalent to saying
$$ f(x) = f(1)^x \, \forall \, x \in \mathbb{Q}$$
since any rational number can be written as the quotient of an integer and a natural number

The first property will be proven by contradiction: let us assume that
$$\exists \, n \in \mathbb{N} : f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \neq \sqrt[n]{f(1)}$$
from that it would follow that
$$f(1) = f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \neq \sqrt[n]{f(1)}^n = f(1)$$
This is a contraciction, therefore it must be so that
$$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \sqrt[n]{f(1)} \, \forall \, n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Now for our second step, let us pick two values $p \in \mathbb{Z}, q \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x = \frac{p}{q}$ making $x$ any rational number
$$ f(x) =  f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^p = \sqrt[q]{f(1)}^{p} = f(1)^{p/q} = f(1)^x$$

Now, we have proven that $f(xn) = f(x)^n \implies f(x) = f(1)^x$ for any rational number $x$, because $f(1)$ is a constant we will give it a new name, $r$ to get that $f(x)$ must be of the form $r^x$. To this we can apply power rules $$f(x+y) = r^{x+y} = r^x r^y = f(x)f(y)$$

Therefore, we have shown that $$f(nx) = f(x)^n \, \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{Z} \implies f(x+y) = f(x)f(y) \, \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$$